# Hive : why is metastore_db created in my project folder?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have put `hive-site.xml` in my `spark/conf` dir and configured it to connect to `thrift://<user>:9083` and I am not using `derby` I have `mysql-connector-jar` inside hive/lib folder , still every time I create hive table and store data , all data are stored in `metastore_db` in my project directory instead in my `hdfs://<user>:9000/user/hive/warehouse`, so if I delete metastore_db data is lost.
`conf/hive-site.xml`

```
<property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:mysql://saurab:3306/metastore_db?
        createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
        <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
        <value>/home/saurab/hadoopec/hive/lib/hive-serde-
       2.1.1.jar</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>spark.sql.warehouse.dir</name>
        <value>hdfs://saurab:9000/user/hive/warehouse</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://saurab:9083</value>
        <description>URI for client to contact metastore 
        server</description>
    </property>
```

[This](https://pastebin.com/tiARTHgb) is my thriftserver log.Mysql server is running.So why it is still creating metastore_db and storing data there.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have made those changes on the Spark conf folder but not on the server one (at least not all of them).
Notice on the server log:
"metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY"

A common practice is instead of copying the config under spark/conf just add a link from there to /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml, to make sure client and server are using the same configuration.

My advice is to setup the server side correctly first (you also have a port conflict), test it with beeline and only them start using it from Spark

Comment: so i should add /hive/conf/ to $SPARK_CLASSPATH ? will this be good

Comment: Also , I was wondering if spark actually reads `/hive/conf/hive-site.xml`. Doesn't it only read `/spark/conf/hive-site.xml` ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Lr8QJJRP Here is `hive/conf/hive-site.xml` . What else did I miss ?

Comment: By default spark/conf is added to the classpath, it's easier to put link there rather than mess with the Spark classpath.
In principle the config looks correct, did you restart the server after making those changes?
The "port already in use" error could indicate a stale server running

Comment: The thrift log is from the HiveServer2, since you are setting "hive.metastore.uris" it means you are running a separate Metastore server.
Are you sure it was restarted since the configuration changes where made?

Comment: I have never been so damn confused in my life. I have written my setup enviroment on this https://pastebin.com/bwu7NG6M . IF there's is any courses that explains setup on production and uses mysql rather than default derby ( I only find tutorials that explains setup with derby ). I would be very grateful.

Comment: There are basically 3 modes you can run hive. What you currently have is the separate metastore, which is the way used by Hortonworks and Cloudera. You don't need the Spark thrift server for this, it's for external clients. Go step by step checking the logs. First start hadoop and mysql, then start the metastore and verify it is using mysql on the log. Then I would start hiveserver2 and use beeline to test creating a table, Then you start the Spark job